# how to disable background attribution in htmlize.el when exporting html

Tags: python, emacs, python-2.7, org-mode, emacs24

now I am using emacs 24.2.1, orgmode 8.0.2, 
 [htmlize.el 1.47](http://fly.srk.fer.hr/~hniksic/emacs/htmlize.el.cgi).

when  exporting html with source code. such as for python. the variable is always attached with a background attribution. The highlight of characters is good enough. The background is really annoying.

Interesting, this issue will appear only when it is python block. the detail as follows:

[image: python variable with background attribution]

could someone help me out?

thanks

Comment: omg, at last using the command **M-x htmlize-buffer**, i found it may be due to the variable "py-number-face" and "py-variable-name-face". then I just set them to nil at .emacs file.

Comment: you may submit your own answer and accept it if it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

omg, at last using the command **M-x htmlize-buffer**, i found it may be due to the variable **py-number-face** and **py-variable-name-face**. then I just set them to nil at .emacs file.